# Search a file for a string and put it into an array

Tags: matlab

The goal of the program is to look through a file for a string and spit out all the instances of that string with the line that the the string was in.

I've gotten it to search through the file and find them, just not able to get them into an array or something that lets me store all of them. Right now it gives me the last instance, I can easily put in one break between line 8 and 9 to find the first instance also.

If anyone knows how to store every line that has the string in question that would be a great help.

```
fid = fopen('....... file directory....')
prompt = 'What string are you searching for?  ';
str = input(prompt,'s');

i=0;
for j=1:10000;
tline = fgetl(fid);             %Returns next line of specified file
counter = counter + 1;          %Counts the next line
    if ischar(tline);           %Checks if the line is an array
    U=strfind(tline,str);       %Sets U to be 1 if strfind finds the string in line tline
        if isfinite(U) == 1                     
            what = tline;       %This is where I want to set the array positions equal to whatever tline is at that time, then move onto the next i and search for the next tline.
            i=i+1;
        end            
    end
end
```

Comment: Can there be more than one instance per line?

Comment: Figured it out. I have an array called 'what' that shows them. But now I need to get specific spots of the array out. Like the string would be 'xdfsdfsd 00 1 2 3 5' and I want to be able to pull out the 1 and 3.

Comment: one more thing that i realize. If i just had a string, doing string(8) would give me the eigth position. But I have an array of strings so how would I got to a specific string of it then find the position of it (also would be a set, like position 8-10)

Comment: If all your lines are the same length then you can use an array of strings. Otherwise you'll want to use cell arrays and store each line of text in a cell.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

```
haystack = 'test.txt';

prompt = 'What string are you searching for?  ';
needle = input(prompt, 's');

% MS Windows
if ispc

    output = regexp(evalc(['!find /N "' needle '" ' haystack]), char(10), 'split');

    output = regexp(output, '^\[([0-9].*)\]', 'tokens');
    output = cellfun(@(x)str2double(x{:}), output(~cellfun('isempty', output)))';

% OSX/Linux   
elseif isunix

    output = regexp(evalc(['!grep -n "' needle '" ' haystack]), char(10), 'split');

    output = regexp(output, '^([0-9].*):', 'tokens');    
    output = cellfun(@(x)str2double(x{:}), output(~cellfun('isempty', output)))';

% Anything else: stay in MATLAB
else

    fid = fopen(haystack);
    output = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
    fclose(fid);

    output = find(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(output{1}, needle)));

end
```

Contents of `test.txt`:

```
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage valuable garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage valuable 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage valuable garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage 
garbage garbage garbage
```

When I execute the code on Windows or Linux or force the MATLAB version, with `needle = 'valuable'`, I get the correct line numbers:

```
output = 
    6   
    8  
   13
```

The advantage of using the OS-specific tools is that they have a far smaller memory footprint than the pure MATLAB version (they don't load the entire file in memory). Even if you would grow the code in MATLAB in order to prevent this (by using a loop with `freadl` for instance), the OS-specific tools will *still* be quite a bit faster (and still more memory friendly); that's why I put it as a final resort :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in struct array, for example:

```
lines = struct([]); % to store lines and line numbers    

idx = 1;

fid = fopen('somefile.txt');

tline = fgets(fid);

while ischar(tline)

    U=strfind(tline, str);

    if numel(U) > 0                            

        lines(end + 1).line = tline; % save line
        lines(end).lineNo = idx;     % save its number 
        lines(end).U = U;            % where is str in the just saved line            

    end

    tline = fgets(fid);

    idx = idx + 1;

end

fclose(fid);

lineTxts    = {lines(:).line};   % get lines in a cell
lineNumbers = [lines(:).lineNo]; % get line numbers as matrix
```